# Create setup package in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

First time I am creating a setup file in visual studio 2010.

I have 2 files in the project file 1 and file 2.
[image: Solution Exp]

When I click on the button I get the file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"FilesOutput\Help\file 1.pdf");
     ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filename, "");
     try
     {
        Process.Start(psi);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     { 
     }    
 }
```

I created the Setup of the project and install it, I see the button, but when I click on the button I cannot see the file.
Can some one can help how to get the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark your files as Content using Solution Explorer and Properties window. Just click on the file in Solution Explorer, go to properties and set `Copy to Output` to `Copy if newer` and `Build Action` to `Content`. Then in the setup project, make sure you have include **Contents** of the Primary Project Output in the File System tab.